# HTTP POST multipart/form-data - no data being sent

Tags: python, http, sockets, server

I'm making a custom HTTP server in python. I won't be using any existing library, only sockets.
I'm trying to make a simple file upload, but this turned out to be unnecessarily hard. For some reason, I'm only ever receiving the headers, and never any actual multipart/form-data.. data.

This is server.py:

```py
import socket

def file(name: str) -> bytes:
    with open(name, "rb") as f:
        return f.read()

serv_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serv_sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
serv_sock.bind(("", 80))
serv_sock.listen(1)

while True:

    client_sock, client_addr = serv_sock.accept()

    data = client_sock.recv(65536)

    client_sock.send(b"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n" + file("index.html"))

    print(data.decode() + "\n\n")
```

This is index.html:

```html
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="upload"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is what gets printed out:

```http
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 888
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Origin: http://localhost
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryVDy2sAnz0KKXq4lr
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Sec-GPC: 1
Accept-Language: en-US,en
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Referer: http://localhost/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
```

No data, no boundary, nothing! I've been banging my head on this, and I have no clue where there's an issue.
any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe the server should keep reading until it has read the whole request?

Answer (score 0):

TCP is a byte stream, it has no concept of message boundaries or application-level protocols (like HTTP). Your code has to manage all of that.

Calling `recv()` will simply give you an *arbitrary* block of bytes. There is no guarantee that you will receive as many bytes as you ask for.  To do anything meaningful, you will have to *interpret* the bytes that you do receive, and be prepared to read more bytes if needed.

In this situation, you need to keep reading until you have received the `\r\n\r\n` separator between the HTTP headers and body, and then you need to *parse* the headers (specifically, the `Transfer-Encoding`, `Content-Length`, and `Content-Type` headers) to discover which format the body is being transmitted in and more importantly to know how to detect when the *end* of the body has been received, and then you need to keep reading until the body's logical end is actually reached.

Refer to [RFC 2616 Section 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4) (particularly 4.2-4.4) and [RFC 7230 Section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3) (particularly 3.2-3.3) for more details.